# What is meant by 'query modification' as an approach to implementing views?

Tags: mysql, sql, view

Just doing some revision, and one of the questions is:

> "Explain what is meant by 'query
>   modification' as an approach to
>   implementing views."

Now, I'm not quite sure how to answer that... I know what views are, how to create them and why they are used etc, but what exactly does that question want to know?

Comment: The answer will definitely be much simpler than the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a theoretical concept from [David Meier's works on relational theory](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~maier/TheoryBook/MAIER/C11.pdf).

When you are using a view in your queries, like this:

```
CREATE VIEW v_filtered
AS
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   mycolumn = 1

SELECT  *
FROM    v_filtered
JOIN    othertable
ON      otherid = myid
```

, to execute your query, a database engine should be able to rewrite the query over the *virtual relations* (like your view) to one using the *base relations*, since that what is actually stored:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
JOIN    othertable
ON      otherid = myid
WHERE   mycolumn = 1
```

This process is called query modification.

Comment: Oh ok, so basically the answer would be along the lines of "a database engine should be able to rewrite the query over the virtual relations (like your view) to one using the base relations"...?

Comment: @ChrisEdwards: don't know if it's exactly what your tutor wants to hear, but yes, something close to that. I'd just reference this book if I did that homework.

Comment: Is this the same as view expansion (i.e. macro expansion) in SQL Server?